# Why is text using my custom colour gradient CSS class not displaying properly on mobile?

Tags: css

**Visible Issue:** http://stage.herotheapp.com/brand-assets
**Problem seen on:** Responsive / mobile view

I recently added a CSS class that I found on a forum to enable the change of text colour to a four-point gradient.

The colour gradient works well, but it has broken how the rest of the text behaves. Most visible on mobile - the text does not line-break cleanly (if at all), line-height is not consistent with theme h1/h2/h3 etc. presets, and is generally illegible.

In a perfect world, I only want the gradient colour override, much like using a  rule so that the rest of the text settings apply the global theme / elementor text styling, but I couldn't find a  rule for gradients.

I have tried word-break and word-wrap rules but neither have worked.

Here is the CSS applied:

```
.rainbowtxt {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #5cb6ea, #5245fc, #aa41b3, #ff6d9f); /* For Chrome and Safari */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #5cb6ea, #5245fc, #aa41b3, #ff6d9f); /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #5cb6ea, #5245fc, #aa41b3, #ff6d9f); /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #5cb6ea, #5245fc, #aa41b3, #ff6d9f); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, #5cb6ea, #5245fc, #aa41b3, #ff6d9f); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
    color:transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    word-wrap:break-all;
    overflow-wrap: inherit;
}
```

It's probably an easy fix, but beyond my WP skillset unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with WordPress. [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) is a css property that create a gradient image, we couple it with the [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) property to mask it to the text. Finally we change the font color to transparent to show the gradient image. Those are the only required properties to change the text to a gradient color.

- `linear-gradient()` has an overall support, no need for browsers prefixes (eg: -webkit-, -moz-, -ms- ...).
- `background-clip` has an overall support but require the `-webkit-` prefixes for support on all [browsers webkit engine based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit). (All beside Firefox and Edge).

```css
.,
.rainbow {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #5cb6ea, #5245fc, #aa41b3, #ff6d9f)!important;
  background-clip: text!important;
  -webkit-background-clip: text!important;
  color: transparent!important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class=" rainbow">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the code - makes perfect sense. This doesn't fix the main issue though of text not breaking properly when using this class.

Comment: then the issue isn't related to this

Comment: Unfortunately it is, because if I remove the CSS styling from the header, they work perfectly fine using the theme settings. This custom CSS is overriding, and not displaying properly.